# React Router component doesn't render despite matching exact route

Tags: reactjs, parameters, routes, blogs

I am building a simple blog with React Router, but facing some problems when changing locations.

Expected behaviour:

1. Route *localhost:8080/#/contact* should display Contact component contents.

Actual behaviour:

1. Route *localhost:8080/#/contact* doesn't render Contact component but only Pagination component navigation links - 1, 2, 3 that is rendered by HomePage component. Please note the comment in code below.

Maybe it has to do with **:page** parameter in path? Both my 1st and 5th route is using it.

Extra questions:

1. How to implement pagination on the HomePage so it does not interfere with other routes?
2. After landing on *localhost:8080/#/* HomePage component displays 1st page of blog posts which technically should be on *localhost:8080/#/1*. Is there a logical workaround that I can use?

my App component:

```
import {
    HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
const App = () => {
        const routes = (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route exact path="/:page?" component={HomePage} /> // commenting this line out causes <Contact /> work properly, but then again pagination on HomePage doesn't work as I don't have parameter in the url.
                <Route exact path="/post/:uid" component={PostPage} />
                <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
                <Route exact path="/category/:category/:page?" component={CategoryPage} />
                <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
        );
    
        return (
            <>
               <MetaDecorator/>
               <Router>
                 {routes}
               </Router>
            </>
        );
    };
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you use the **#** in your examples? This is not neccessary in React and if you actually made the Links to point to '#/contacts' for example it won't work.

Comment: I am using HashRouter as Router, so this is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch always looks through the routes and renders the first route that matches with your routes.

In this example, you put the `/:page` route to the top of the Switch. When react router looks for your route, it thinks that, `"contact"` word in `"/contact"` is a page id and it should render the `/:page` route.

You should put the `/:page` route before "not found" and try to delete `exact` keywords from your routes except `/`.

```js
return (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/post/:uid" component={PostPage} />
    <Route path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
    <Route path="/category/:category/:page?" component={CategoryPage} />
    <Route path="/:page?" component={HomePage} />
    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Switch>
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Also try to use `<BrowserRouter>` instead of Router.

I hope your problem will be fixed.